# Issue with the NPM

Tags: git, jenkins, docker, npm, bower

When I try to run the build, it uses NPM and Bower dependencies. It uses bower dependencies and it fails at any point (as its the random pick of the bower dependencies). Some dependencies works perfect and some fails to clone. When I try to run the build again the failed dependency will clone and it fails in cloning the other dependencies. I have set the proxy for NPM in Dockerfile.

Error message is given below:

ECMDERR Failed to execute "git clone https://github.com/handsontable/ngHandsontable.git -b 0.7.0-beta2 --progress . --depth 1", exit code of #128
�
Its the same exit code of #128 for all the dependencies when ever it fails to clone.

Its not the issue with the proxy I believe because the build was successful when I tried locally in my terminal and when I tried running the same build again without making any changes it fails, I'm not sure, why it happens. Can someone please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not give the complete log it could a caching issue with Bower. Try to clean your Bower cache.

```
bower cache clean
```

That should do it.

Comment: This should be a `bower cache clean`.

Comment: Good addition, didn't know about that one. I will change my answer.